# NodeJs error while trying to run site

Tags: node.js, express

So I've been doing the build a voting app challenge for a while and I finished the signup & login part, but then I ran into a problem that I don't understand why it happens:

whenever I try to go to the "polls" section, it gave me an error of:

```
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/views/polls.ejs:2
    1| <%include header.ejs %>
 >> 2| <%include nav.ejs %>
    3| <div id = "home" class = "container">
    4|     <h1>Polls</h1>
    5| </div>

esc is not a function
```

PS lines 1~5 is everything I have in my polls.ejs file

Here is my code for the polls.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('polls');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my code for the nav.ejs file:

```
  <body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-full navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #0099ff;">
      <div class="container">
        <% if(authenticated === false){ %>
          <a  id="title" class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="color: #dddddd">FFC Voting App</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-sm-right" style = "float: right;">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/polls">Polls</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login In</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
      <% }else{ %>
          <a  id="title" class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="color: #dddddd">FFC Voting App</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-sm-right" style = "float: right;">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/polls">Polls</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/mypolls">My Polls</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      <%}%>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

The strange thing here is that if I take out the if/ else statement for the nav.ejs file, it works perfectly fine, but when I add it on, it gives me the error.

Does anyone know why it happens and how I can solve it?

Comment: Are you sure `authenticated` returns true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esc is not a function` is the `ejs` way of saying that you have an undefined variable.

In this case it means that your variable `authenticated` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you Jivings! Turns out I had to define the authenticated function again in my polls.js file. Now it all works!

Comment: @ElisaL No problem, use the `tick` on the left to mark this question as answered :)